# Hidden/Invisible Layers Becoming Visible in "Export for Screens"

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, export

I'm having a problem in Illustrator when trying to "Export for Screens" where non-visible layers appear in those exports.

In the "Export for Screens" preview window (**B.**), these layers are invisible - as they should be - until I click "export" and they pop up in the folder showing those invisible layers (**C.**).

I went under File>Print and set "Print layers" to "Visible layers" - to no avail.

I have many artboards in this file and I wish to batch export them - "Export for Screens" is a great way to do this, but not when this happens!

Thank you for your time!

**A.**) [image: the artboard I wish to export, in Illustrator]
**B.**) [image: the artboard I wish to export, in "Export for Screens" preview]
**C.**) [image: the artboard I have exported, in the destination folder]

Comment: I overprint preview on? (View menu)

Comment: @scott just turned it on and exported - same results

Comment: You want it *off* which is why I was checking.

Comment: @Scott either way, same results

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior,  hidden layers are not exported using the asset export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the best solution I found is to just use a 3rd party script (MultiExporter) to export "artboard images"

Link to script: https://gist.github.com/TomByrne/

[image]